# Optimize query with composite index

Tags: mysql, mariadb, composite-index

"I'm having trouble with a query that uses a composite index. When I use a regular index, the query takes about 1 second to execute on a table with 3 million rows. However, when I add a composite index, the query only improves by about 0.982 seconds or 0.88 seconds, which isn't a significant improvement. The composite index I created is CREATE OR REPLACE INDEX idx ON bill_lading (c, k, p, cli). However, when I run EXPLAIN on the query, it only shows that the c_date index is being used, not the composite index. Can you help me understand how to use the composite index effectively?"

```
SELECT
`id`,
`cav`,
`cave`,

FROM
`b` 
WHERE 
`c` = '0' 
AND `k` = '1' 
AND `p` = '0' 
AND `cli` IN ( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '11' ) 
AND `c_date` <= '2021-02-15 23:59:59' 
AND ((
    `cav` <> '0' 
    AND ( `c_check_id` <> '0' OR `number_r` = '1' ) 
    AND `status` = '3' 
    ) 
  OR (
    `cav` = '0' 
  AND `status` IN ( '1', '2' ))) 
ORDER BY
`id` ASC 
LIMIT 200 OFFSET 400;
```

NOTE: all column `c`, `k`, `p`, `cli`,`c_date`, `c_check_id`, `status` have single index in table `b`

Comment: You could try using index hints (USE_INDEX/ FORCE INDEX) to see if there is any improvement, then using EXPLAIN to examine the query plan in these using index hints cases.

Comment: When you ask an optimization question, please include the CREATE TABLE statement and output of the EXPLAIN command.

Comment: @TrungDuong "Thank you for reminding me of the FORCE INDEX command. I tried using it, but it was even slower than before. I think I should examine the table more closely and try creating a better composite index."